# Model import generating self-intersecting warnings that weren’t there before

Tags: unity, maya

Starting with Unity 2018, when importing my model (FBX) I am getting dozens of "A polygon of [name of the mesh] is self-intersecting and has been discarded“ warnings. This is new! The model looks fine when imported despite these warnings, but this model is part of a package I sell on the Asset Store since, I am in the process of updating the asset and at the very least this looks terrible for customers purchasing this asset. Unfortunately, the warning message gives no further clues *which* polygons are now offending. FWIW the model was created in Maya. Does anyone have any advice on how I can track this down and fix this without breaking the prefabs?

Comment: What happens when you run Mesh > Mesh Cleanup ... in Maya on the offending meshes?

Answer (score 2):

I just crossed my fingers that it wouldn't merge unwanted vertices and used "Merge vertices" in Maya. This worked for 95% of the affected polygons, the others were comparatively easy to find manually because their faces were large and Unity discarded them on import. Fortunately, replacing the fbx when exporting the mesh to the project doesn't break anything, unless you mess up the meshes in the fbx itself.